# Change height of bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: css, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a bootstrap form of which I made the input fields very small (since I have many fields).
Now on some dropdown menus I have implemented the selectpicker bootstrap, but it is too big compared to the other fields, I would like to make it smaller but I can't.
For normal input fields I have created a new class form-control-xs

```
.form-control-xs {
    height: 20px;
    padding: .025rem .25rem !important;
    font-size: .75rem !important;
    line-height: 0;
    border-radius: .2rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But for the selectpicker I can't in any way change its height. If I can, the inside gets messed up.
Here you see the height difference, i would like that they have the same height.

[image]

This is the code I use now for the selectpicker:

```
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <label for="dipartimento" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">LABEL</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">

                                <select name="dipartimento" id="dipartimento" class="form-control form-control-sm"  data-live-search="true" title="Select" >
                                    <?PHP
                                    // i generate the <option> from the mysql
                                    ?>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            $("#dipartimento").selectpicker("render");
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add !importent on height

```css
height: 20px !importent;
```